# Is Google's speech recognition free on business or free apps?

Tags: android, mobile

I'm using the Android speech API in conjunction with the Google servers and Google search app (installed by default on my Android device) to make speech recognition possible on my app, which I want to publish on Google play.

Is there any cost for using Google's speech recognition on a business or free app?

Comment: It is free, I reckon. Otherwise they would have included it in Google Console.